# Comparing the marginal effect of a GLM to the OLS estimates

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, least-squares, model-comparison, quasi-likelihood

My question is, whether there is any way to (somewhat) compare the **marginal effect** of a GLM estimate to an OLS estimate. As in, "since the OLS and GLM results are very similar, I will favour OLS because of ease of interpretation"

If the answer is a hard no, I would still be very interested in why this is a no.

In my example `Crime` is a dummy variable (I have recoded it as such).

My example output is as follows:

```
lm_1st <- glm(lm_form_1st, ,data=full)

                                Estimate Std. Error t value             Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                    0.7896258  0.0792442   9.964 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
Crime                          0.3824961  0.0214503  17.832 < 0.0000000000000002 ***


glm_1st <- glm(glm_form_1st, family="quasipoisson", data=full); summary(glm_1st)
summary(margins(glm_1st, variables = "Crime"))

                                Estimate Std. Error t value             Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                   -0.2140713  0.0875054  -2.446             0.014438 *  
Crime                          0.3524041  0.0221681  15.897 < 0.0000000000000002 **

factor    AME     SE       z      p  lower  upper
Crime 0.3302 0.0209 15.7771 0.0000 0.2892 0.3712   # Marginal effect of the GLM
```

## Related questions:

[How does OLS regression relate to generalised linear modelling](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/211585/how-does-ols-regression-relate-to-generalised-linear-modelling)

[How to determine if GLS improves on OLS?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/155031/how-to-determine-if-gls-improves-on-ols)

[The interpretation of a positive glm coefficient, with a negative marginal effect](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/520009/the-interpretation-of-a-positive-glm-coefficient-with-a-negative-marginal-effec)

Comment: What are the values of `crime`?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus In this case `Crime` is a dummy variable. Sorry, I realise that I should have added that. I'll add it with my question about marginal effects as well.

Comment: *question = other questions